# ASP.NET Membership Get logged on user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I had define a username in and I added it to a role.

Now, I use this code to check if user valid:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)) {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUsername.Text, false);
    if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(txtUsername.Text).Any(role => role == "Admin")) {
        Page.Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/Admin/Products.aspx"));
    }
    txtUsername.Text = "";
}
```

After that, I want to check in Products.aspx page if user is in a role or not. I wrote this code but it returns my local Windows username :

```
Context.User.Identity.Name
```

I thinks it *should* returns logged on user.

After that I will check with this code :

```
  if (!Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx"));

        }
```

---

What's wrong with my code? How can I check for that if logged on user is in specific role?

Comment: Reads like maybe you're not parsing the cookie during a post back.  Let me see if I can pull some code for you on that.  It's about 12 lines, and I grabbed it from code project at the time... Would get it now, but am reading on an iPad.

Comment: @RichardB thanks. please put the code if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you set the `authentication-mode` to `Forms`?

**Web.config:**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
</authentication>
```

Also you should use `Page.User.Identity.Name` instead of `Context.User.Identity.Name`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to use `Page.User.Identity.Name`, instead of `Context`.

Let me know if that does it, I've made that mix-up before =)

Comment: Thanks for attention :] But no way ! It didn't work 
Page.User.Identity.Name returns Current user of windows !!

Comment: @shaahin Shoot!  Well, good luck!  If I think of anything else I'll try again haha.

Comment: Page.User is just a utility property that returns the value of context.User, ie they are the same thing